# Solrj create query from string

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have a SOLR query in "query string" format like

```
q=*&fq=myfilters&...
```

Is there a way to build a SolrQuery from that?

I've seen that exists ClientUtils.toQueryString, basically I need the reverse operation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

Solrj provides its own methods of querying (parallel to what you posted above) like for filter query, solr.addFilterQuery(...). here is a good start point :-> http://www.solrtutorial.com/solrj-tutorial.html

Comment: That API is completely abstracted away from the query itself, which is kind of convoluted, if you already have a query string that Solr understands...